# Python - Error (not all arguments converted during string formatting) when calling a function

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I am trying to call a sql script using python as below:

```
def employees(email_address):
    cursor = conn.cursor() .  <- DB Connection
    cursor.execute("""select name from employees where email_address =(%s)""", (email_address))
    employee = cursor.fetchall()
```

This returns an error

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong in the above. Thanks

Comment: I will asume you are using pymysql. In such case, use `email_address = %(email_address)s`, and use `{'email_address': email_address}` as the second parameter.

Comment: @halfelf running this on a redshift Db.

Comment: postgre then. I guess it's the same API, specified by PEP 249.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need to add a `%` instead of a comma after the string:</strike>

Edit: my bad, actually you need to pass your arguments as a tuple so you want to use `(email_address,)` instead of `(email_address)`:

```
def employees(email_address):
    cursor = conn.cursor() .  <- DB Connection
    cursor.execute("""select name from employees where email_address =(%s)""", (email_address,))
    employee = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: No, you absolutely do not. This would bypass the parameterisation functionality and leave the code open to SQL injection.

Comment: Then how do you put a variable in a string in Python without using `%` or `.format`?

Comment: This isn't "put a variable in a string". This is "insert a parameter into an SQL query".